# Replacing battery on Asus laptop

Tags: laptop, battery

So I have an Asus X554L for couple of years now and I used it mostly for gaming which took tall on a battery cycles. When I bought it it could do straight 6 hours of web browsing or watching movies, now it can go up to 1.5 hours. I want to replace a battery with new one and I already read somewhere online that voltage is important to match and the higher 'Ah' I can get the better.

After opening my laptop I saw my battery specs, and those are 7.5V (37Wh), 4.829Ah and a serial number C21N1347. So I looked on the online shops and found a similar battery (**7.6V 38Wh**) and it's for **Asus X555**, but it has the same serial number (C21N1347).

So my question is should I buy this battery, will it work on my laptop?

Comment: Have you contacted the seller and asked this question?  I would also asked the seller what their refund policy is exactly.

Comment: Well I have not, because usually shops that sell tech around here don't know that kind of stuff. And on the Asus official website I couldn't find anything either.